# How is the name of the blue visualization in a TextView on a click?

Tags: android, textview, effects

When I click on a TextView without any own attributes, the TextView gets shortly blue and than the blue color gets more and more transparency. What is the name of this effect in developer-language? Firstly, I guess it is called "tint" but this seems not correct.
I need the name to search for it in stackoverflow and documentation.

Comment: Do you mean the 'ripple effect' ?

Comment: Correct! Thanks!